# Can't screenshot crypto wallet pages using puppeteer

Tags: node.js, puppeteer, screenshot

I like to monitor my wallets on [etherscan.io](https://etherscan.io), [zerion.io](https://zerion.io) and [solana.com](https://solana.com) by capturing a screenshot of the pages using puppeteer. This used to work fine, but lately I'm getting blocked by a captcha (specifically Cloudflare) and can't take a screenshot of the pages.

I have tried the following proposed solutions:

- use [puppeteer extra stealth](https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth) npm package
- [random-useragents](https://www.npmjs.com/package/random-useragent) npm package,
- [static UA](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71929124/8853312)
- data center/residential proxies, etc
- running in headless and 'headful' mode
- mimicking different viewports

None of these above have resolved the issue

Full code example: https://runkit.com/microworlds/62dfada6d02c0d0008e9f997

How do I bypass the captchas/firewalls for these crypto sites?

Comment: Have you tried anything from the dupes? [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64314346/puppeteer-bypass-cloudflare-by-enable-cookies-and-javascript), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71923946/cloudflare-bypass-with-puppeteer),  [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68696073/puppeteer-cloudflare-websites-return-403-forbidden), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55678095/bypassing-captchas-with-headless-chrome-using-puppeteer/55714786#55714786) etc. For example, you could start by adding a user agent.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cloudflare bypass with Puppeteer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71923946/cloudflare-bypass-with-puppeteer)

Comment: @ggorlen I've tried all the recommended options (using stealth mode with puppeteer extra, rotating UAs, static UA, residential proxies, etc.) Unfortunately, none of these settings works. Here's my approach (glued together from some of the recommendations) - https://runkit.com/microworlds/62dfada6d02c0d0008e9f997

Comment: Can you put it into the question here and list everything you tried so far? Thanks.